# How to iterate and update 1 value through Dynamodb nested attributes using DynamodDB adapter for Alexa Skill?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using the DynamoDb Adapter for the alexa skills. FYI, I'm very new to development so apologies if the question is silly.

```python
from ask_sdk_dynamodb.adapter import DynamoDbAdapter
```

I have a persistent attribute in dynamodb that is nested like this. At least this is what I initially saved into the attribute.

```python
enqueue_data = {
    "ENQUEUE": [
        {
            "link_enqueue": "http://link1.com",
            "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue": "numerical value",
            "title": "title 1"
        },
        {
            "link_enqueue": "http://link2.com",
            "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue": "numerical value",
            "title": "title 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

but in dynamodb the format looks like this. This is a snapshot of a portion of it.

```python
{ "link" : { "S" : "http://link1.com" },{ "ENQUEUE" : { "L" : [ { "M" : { "title_enqueue" : { "S" : "Title 1" }, "link_enqueue" : { "S" : "http://link1.com" }, "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue" : { "N" : "15645" } } }, { "M" : { "title_enqueue" : { "S" : "title 2" }, "link_enqueue" : { "S" : "http://link2.com" }, "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue" : { "N" : "52546" } } }
```

First, I'm getting the selected_link variable value from the attributes with this which works really well.

```python
#selected_link = http://link1.com
selected_link = attr['link']
```

then I have the following code. I'm trying to iterate on what I have in dynamodb;

1. Find if the ENQUEUE key value exists
2. If it exists iterate through the link_enqueue value until it matches the selected_link variable
3. If there is a match, then update a different key value.

Example:
If selecte_link is http://link1.com
Find http://link1.com in ENQUEUE, and if so, update offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue to a new value

```py
    def handle(self, handler_input):
        offset_in_milliseconds = '3232'
        
        #getting the attribute from dynamodb
        attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
        
        #getting link value 
        selected_link = attr['link']

        # Check if 'ENQUEUE' key exists in persistent attributes
        if 'ENQUEUE' in attr:
            enqueue_data = attr['ENQUEUE']

            # Check if 'link_enqueue' is present in any item within 'ENQUEUE'
            relevant_items = [item for item in enqueue_data.values() if item.get('link_enqueue') == selected_link]

            if relevant_items:
                relevant_item = relevant_items[0]  
                # Assuming you want the first relevant item
                relevant_item['offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue'] = offset_in_milliseconds
                # Save the updated persistent attributes
                handler_input.attributes_manager.save_persistent_attributes()
                return
            return
        return
```

Ideally the new attribute should have the new value in the offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue because the selected_link match the link_enqueue. Everything else should stay the same.

```python
enqueue_data = {
    "ENQUEUE": [
        {
            "link_enqueue": "http://link1.com",
            "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue": "new numerical value",
            "title": "title 1"
        },
        {
            "link_enqueue": "http://link2.com",
            "offset_in_milliseconds_enqueue": "numerical value",
            "title": "title 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to overcome the complexity of DynamoDB-JSON is to deserialize into standard JSON. You can do this easily from a built in Boto3 utility.

A quick read of this blog should set you up to easily handle JSON and make your update logic much easier:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Comment: great, this is very helpful, thank you

Comment: Excellent, feel free to a accept the answer if it works for you.